# Is it possible to add custom rectangluar boxes in piechart in each ontap in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter_charts package for charts section. I want get on  each Ontap of piechart, I want t o get a rectangular boxes. It's working in linechart and barchart. But I have tried as like in pie chart, it's not working.

Does anyone have done it with this feature, please update it.
It will very helpful for my future work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AnnotationConfig` class to add custom rectangular boxes on the chart. You would need to provide the `AnnotationConfig` to the pie chart widget and configure the rectangles as desired.

Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class MyPieChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  MyPieChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.PieChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcRendererDecorators: [
        new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
            labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.outside)
      ]),
      behaviors: [
        new charts.DatumLegend(
          entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
              color: charts.MaterialPalette.purple.shadeDefault,
              fontFamily: 'Georgia',
              fontSize: 18),
        ),
        new charts.ChartTitle('My Custom Pie Chart'),
        new charts.AnnotationChart(
            [
              new charts.AnnotationSegment(
                  0.5,
                  0.5,
                  charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#ff0000'),
                  charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#ff0000'),
                  5.0,
                  5.0)
            ],
            defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                arcWidth: 60,
                arcRendererDecorators: [
                  new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                      labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.auto)
                ])),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, The `AnnotationSegment` class is used to create a new annotation segment, with the following parameters:

0.5 and 0.5 are the X and Y coordinate of the annotation.

`charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#ff0000')` is the fill color of the rectangle.

5.0 and 5.0 are width and height of the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for this. But i want to make tooltip behaivour instead of this. When clicking each items in pei charts, i want to show specific parts all details in that tooltip section